# Assigning variable values to if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, if-statement, assign

```
if GPA == unweighted:
A+ = 4.33
A = 4
A- = 3.67
B+ = 3.33
B = 3.0
value1 = credits*grade1
```

Ok so I am trying to assign those number values to those variables if the if statement is true, but when I run the program, it says there is a syntax error. Can someone please help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: [Identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use operators as part of the identifiers for your variables. Full explanation in the [Python docs about identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

The Python interpreter will identify the `+` and `-` as actual code to execute and not as part of you variables names like `A+`.

In Python as well as in other programming languages the only allowed characters for variable identifiers are letters (`a-z`, `A-Z`), numbers (`0-9`) and underscore (`_`). Though keep in mind there is an extra rule that specified you can't start an identifier with a number as well. Additional to that, in Python 3 (via [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)) support was added for non-ASCII characters, meaning you could even write your variables in Russian (`картофель = 10`).

I would rename those variables as `a_plus`, `a_minus` o `b_plus`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: @BruhKey: As per the valid syntaxes for variable names in python, arithmetic operators like +, -, /, *, ^, = etc. cannot be used in variable names.

Comment: when defining your variables, you are using operators like `-` (minus which is used for substraction) inside your variable identifiers ('names'), e.g. in `A-`. This is not possible in python Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dictionary?   You can store the weighted and unweighted grade scales with the grades as keys.

```
gpa = {
    'unweighted':
        {
        'A+' : 4.33,
        'A'  : 4,
        'A-' : 3.67,
        'B+' : 3.33,
        'B'  : 3.0,
        'B-' : 2.67
        },
    'weighted':
        {
        'A+' : 4.67,
        'A'  : 4.3
        }
    }
```